# Notification icon

Tags: iphone

How can i add notification icon on a button..I m able to add it on application icon but not on the button...Help me pls...

```
UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1; // set to any integer
```

I m using this code..
Thank you....

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could better describe your problem or requirement, then people will have a better chance of answering your question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some custom views. Here is the nice one: [link](http://www.spaulus.com/2010/08/eigene-custom-iphone-ipad-badges-erstellen/)

Comment: In this link what CustomBadge,i mean what is it's type bcz it's giving me the error that CustomBadge undeclared....

Comment: That's because you have to download the source from here http://www.spaulus.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/CustomBadge.zip  and add that class to your project

Answer (score 0):

While some classes may have private APIs to add such icons, I believe the only class that publicly supports it is `UITabBarItem`.

Your best bet would be to create your own custom view class that draws the icon appropriately, and then layer it on top of your button (e.g. by adding it as a subview of the button at the proper position).